# How to replace one character in every row of a column

Tags: r, replace, stata

I have a column containing the following strings:

```
1997.2 
1998.3 
2000.1 
2003.3
2008.4
```

I would like to replace every period `.` with the letter `q`.

How can I do this, either in R or Stata?

Comment: Try `?gsub` in R

Comment: I psychically sense that you may also avoid the whole issue by running `lubridate::yq`. E.g. `lubridate::yq("1997.3")` gives `"1997-07-01"`

Answer (score 1):

In R.

Consider your string is `x <- c("1997.2", "1998.3", "2000.1", "2003.3","2008.4")`, then you can use `gsub` to find and replace.

```
> gsub("\\.", "q", x)
[1] "1997q2" "1998q3" "2000q1" "2003q3" "2008q4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `chartr` in `R`

```
chartr(".", "q", x)
#[1] "1997q2" "1998q3" "2000q1" "2003q3" "2008q4"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("1997.2", "1998.3", "2000.1", "2003.3","2008.4")
```

Answer (score 1):

As @dash2 implies for R, you won't be much better off with such a string variable (not column) in Stata. You need a quarterly date variable which numerically is the number of quarters from the first quarter of 1960 and which is formatted as you please. Here I just use the default format for quarterly dates.

The essentials are all documented under `help datetime`:

```
 clear 
 input str6 yourproblem 
 1997.2 
 1998.3 
 2000.1 
 2003.3 
 2008.4
 end 

 gen yoursolution = yq(real(substr(yourprob, 1, 4)), real(substr(yourprob, -1, 1)))

 format yoursol %tq 

 list 

      +---------------------+
     | yourpr~m   yourso~n |
     |---------------------|
  1. |   1997.2     1997q2 |
  2. |   1998.3     1998q3 |
  3. |   2000.1     2000q1 |
  4. |   2003.3     2003q3 |
  5. |   2008.4     2008q4 |
     +---------------------+
```

This also works:

```
gen alsoworks = quarterly(subinstr(yourprob, ".", " ", .), "YQ")
format alsoworks %tq
```

Answer (score 0):

In Stata you can replace using `subinstr()` function.

For your case, you can use the following:

```
replace X = subinstr(X, ".", "q", .)
```

Here, `X` is your string variable. Read about `subinstr()` in Stata's help by typing `help subinstr()` in Stata

Answer (score 0):

Stata has datetime variables that are integers with a special format label attached so that they are readable (for example zero is 1960q1, one is 1960q2, and so on). This allows you to use time series commands, operators and calculate durations. I suggest you convert your string to the year-quarter one. If you still want to keep the data as a string, then the second approach should work:

```
clear
input str8 str_yq
1997.2
1998.3
2000.1
2003.3
2008.4
end
gen yq = quarterly(str_yq,"YQ")
format yq %tq
gen yq2 = subinstr(str_yq,".","q",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers provided in this thread pretty much cover the topic nicely.

In addition to the excellent responses from @Nick and @Dimitriy, i would like to 
demonstrate a related approach in Stata using solely the `substr()` function:

```
clear

input str8 string1
1997.2
1998.3
2000.1
2003.3
2008.4
end

generate string2 = substr(string1, 1, 4) + "q" + substr(string1, 6, 1)
```

Alternatively, if your year length was not fixed in some cases, (i.e. say you
had 97 instead of 1997) you could combine the above with the `strpos()` function:

```
generate string3 = substr(string1, 1, strpos(string1, ".")-1) + "q" + ///
                   substr(string1, strpos(string1, ".")+1, 1)
```

In both cases, the result is the same:

```
list

   +-----------------------------+
   | string1   string2   string3 |
   |-----------------------------|
1. |  1997.2    1997q2    1997q2 |
2. |  1998.3    1998q3    1998q3 |
3. |  2000.1    2000q1    2000q1 |
4. |  2003.3    2003q3    2003q3 |
5. |  2008.4    2008q4    2008q4 |
   +-----------------------------+
```

Note that my solution is provided for purely ***paedagogical*** reasons and i would also strongly recommend using an approach that creates a numeric variable.